# MySQL : SELECT Query

Tags: mysql

I have a table name item_data which have following columns and values in this:

```
id | name |value | price | matching_item
1  | item1|  5   | 1500  | NULL
2  | item2|  6   | 1700  | NULL
3  | item3|  4   |  500  | item1
4  | item3|  8   | 2000  | NULL
```

I have used a select query:

```
SELECT * from `item_data` WHERE (value = 4) AND (price > 100);
```

then it gives me result like that:

```
id | name |  value | price | matching_item
3  | item3|    4   |   500 |    item1
```

but I want a query which give me result like:

```
id | name |  value | price | matching_item
3  | item3|    4   | 500   |    item1
1  | item1|    5   | 1500  |   NULL
```

I want paired result.

Comment: how do you mean "paired result"? based on which attributes and conditions do you want to select items?

Comment: I can give you a bunch of query that will return given result, but where is logic?

Comment: How long a chain of matched items could there be? Could it go item4->item1->item3->item99..... Could there be loops in the matching item ie going item1->item3->item4?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to alter your conditions:

```
 SELECT * from item_data WHERE value IN (4,5) AND (price > 100)
```

Comment: Requirements are so vague.

Answer (score 0):

Without really understanding your question (please be more descriptive), my guess is you want to join the matching_item column in your found results back to the name column and return that row with the found results?

If so, consider using UNION to get your desired result:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM Item_Data i
  LEFT JOIN Item_Data i2 on i.matching_item = i2.name
WHERE i.value = 4 and i.price > 100
UNION
SELECT i2.*
FROM Item_Data i
  INNER JOIN Item_Data i2 on i.matching_item = i2.name
WHERE i.value = 4 and i.price > 100
```

And the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7aab1/3).

Here is a different approach without UNION:

```
SELECT i3.*
FROM Item_Data i
  LEFT JOIN Item_Data i2 on i.matching_item = i2.name
  LEFT JOIN Item_Data i3 on i3.id in (i.id, i2.id)
WHERE i.value = 4 and i.price > 100
```

And the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7aab1/4).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want this:

```
select *
from item_data i
where exists (select *
              from item_data d
              WHERE 
              (
                value = 4 
                AND price > 100
                and i.id = d.id
              )
              or i.name = d.matching_item);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79d5f/17)

Returns the result:

```
| ID |  NAME | VALUE | PRICE | MATCHING_ITEM |
----------------------------------------------
|  1 | item1 |     5 |  1500 |        (null) |
|  3 | item3 |     4 |   500 |         item1 |
```